# How to know if test case fail or pass when using Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, webdriver

I have a beginner question here, in `Selenium IDE` we can know if the test case pass or fail from the Runs: 5 (green color) or Failures: 1 (red color). 
Also, each step will be highlighted in green (pass) or in red (fail). 
We can also set `assert` or `verify`.

In `Webdriver` using `Eclipse` Editor, when running the code, can we see something green or red to highlight which test step fails/ pass ? 
If not, what is the best practice to know which step fail/pass when testing using `Webdriver`?

Cheers.

Comment: Do you have some code that you already have tried with? And are you using `Junit`/`TestNG` or what?

Comment: I am creating my codes now. First of all, I just want to make sure that Webdriver can call each and every element in the web. After that, my plan is to create some scenarios to automate the testing. Now I am wondering, since webdriver don't have its own interface , but we just use Eclipse as editor, run it, and we can see Selenium is opening a web browser and do all the scenarios. How can Webdriver show us pass or fail? UFT has its own GUI to see something, while Webdriver doesn't.

Comment: `WebDriver` has been around for a good bit of time and most famous automation tool out there that drives the browser. I am not sure what is your plan and pass fail depends on the Test runner I believe and all of them have different ways to represent results

Comment: Maybe I need to put it this way. When Selenium Webdriver is running and doing automated testing over the weekend. On Monday morning, I would like to check the test results and analyze the log. Can Webdriver give me some nice test results and log, so it would be easy to know which steps are fine (pass), which steps are occasionally fail, and which steps always fails? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To verify if the test went as expected you need to use **Assertions**

All Selenium Assertions can be used in 3 modes
1. assert
2. verify
3. waitfor